# Extract URLs from HTML and JS source, with multiple on a line

Tags: javascript, regex, bash, zsh

I'd like to list all the domains our source code refers to, allowing the limitation of finding only those that are statically referenced and begin with https?://. For example, I've tried the following:

```
find -s [^.]* -print0 | xargs -0 sed -En 's/.*https?:\/\/([a-z0-9\-\.\_]+).*/\1/p' | sort | uniq
```

The bug is, when there's more than one domain on a single line, only one will be returned. Can this be remedied with simple shell tools, ie without fully parsing the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `.*` is greedy, so putting it at both the beginning and end of your regex will discard any other URLs that are on the same line.

Standard `grep` is unable to print capture groups like `([a-z0-9-._]+)`, but if you have `perl`, replace this:

```sh
sed -En 's/.*https?:\/\/([a-z0-9\-\.\_]+).*/\1/p'
```

with this:

```sh
perl -nle 'print $1 while m{https?://([a-z0-9-._]+)}g'
```

- `https?://([a-z0-9-._]+)` is our new regular expression that matches only what we're looking for, keeping each line intact.
- `while m{...}g` iterates through each match of the regex.
- `print $1` displays the first capture of our regex `([a-z0-9-._]+)`

Your final command will be:

```sh
find -s [^.]* -print0 | xargs -0 perl -nle 'print $1 while m{https?://([a-z0-9-._]+)}g' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Good idea. For other readers, m{}g is equivalent to //g, but avoids backslashing slashes.